# Finding the area under the curve of a probability distribution function in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels, calculus, probability-density

I'm working on a univariate problem which involves aggregating payment data on a customer level - so that I have one row per customer, and the total amount they've spent with us.

Using this distribution of payment data, I fit an appropriate probability distribution and calculated the maximum likelihood estimates for the parameters of the pdf.

Now I want to find the 90th percentile of the distribution. If I was to do this by hand I would set .10 equal to the integral from x to infinity of my pdf and then solve for x.

Is there a package in python/scipy/statsmodels that allows me to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: @razdi - I haven't tried to do it manually yet - just looking to see if there might be a method in `scipy` or `statsmodule` that might make this easy for me, I haven't been able to find one myself.

Comment: Eureka! It's the .`interval()` method for a `rv_continuous` object in `scipy.stats`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (?):

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9])

np.percentile(a, 50)

5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Eureka! It's the `.interval()` method for a rv_continuous object in `scipy.stats` - just pass in your parameters and it will give you end points that contain that percentage of the distribution.

Comment: `interval()` delivers the  "_Confidence interval with equal areas around the median_". Why didnt you ask for that ? "_Now I want to find the 90th percentile of the distribution_" is not exactely the same.